# Maximum Likelihood Classification with No Output using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, file-geodatabase, image-classification

I'm working on a project in ArcMap 10.7.1 and I'm having trouble with the Maximum Likelihood Classification function. I created four classes in my training sample manager (25 samples for 3 of the classes and 10 samples for the 4th class), saved it as a .gsg file, and inputted all the necessary inputs into the Maximum Likelihood Classification window. Afterwards, the usual tab pops up to say that the geoprocessing was successful, but nothing shows up either in ArcMap or in my file geodatabase.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Edit: The solution was to turn off background geoprocessing (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/foreground-and-background-processing.htm). These instructions are for ArcMap 10.3 but I'm using 10.7 and they work just fine.